# Trying to define predefined data type (overwrite)

Tags: java

I am new to java and working on a school assignment. When I run this program it gives an average of test scores but when I enter '999' to exit. It gives me an average number = 'NaN' but I need to have it say 0

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScoreApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // display operational messages
        System.out.println("Enter test scores that range from 0 to 100.");
        System.out.println("To end the program, enter 999.");
        System.out.println();  // print a blank line

        // initialize variables and create a Scanner object
        int scoreTotal = 0;
        int scoreCount = 0;
        int testScore = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // get a series of test scores from the user
        while (testScore != 999) {
            // get the input from the user
            System.out.print("Enter score: ");
            testScore = sc.nextInt();

            // makes average score 0
            if (999 == testScore) {
                double averageScore;
            averageScore = 0;
        }
            // accumulate score count and score total
            if (testScore <= 100) {
                scoreCount = scoreCount + 1;
                scoreTotal = scoreTotal + testScore;
            } else
                System.out.println("Invalid entry: not counted"); 
        }


        // display the score count, score total, and average score

        double averageScore = (double) scoreTotal / scoreCount;
                if (averageScore == 0) {
                    System.out.println("0");
        } 
        String message = "\n"
                + "Score count:   " + scoreCount + "\n"
                + "Score total:   " + scoreTotal + "\n"
                + "Average score: " + averageScore + "\n";
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

I've been working on this program for like 3 hours now and help would be greatly appreciated. Even a redirect to an archived post would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enter any other scores before `999`?  If not, you're `scoreCount` will be zero and you will have committed division by zero when computing your average.  The solution: don't divide the `scoreTotal` by `scoreCount` when `scoreCount == 0`; in that case, the average is just zero:

```
double averageScore = 0;
if (scoreCount != 0) 
    avergageScore = scoreTotal / scoreCount;

// or, if you like the ternary operator better:

double averageScore = 
    (scoreCount == 0) 
       ? 0 
       : (scoreTotal / scoreCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create the `double avarageScore` before you enter the `while` loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScoreApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // display operational messages
        System.out.println("Enter test scores that range from 0 to 100.");
        System.out.println("To end the program, enter 999.");
        System.out.println();  // print a blank line

        // initialize variables and create a Scanner object
        int scoreTotal = 0;
        int scoreCount = 0;
        int testScore = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        double averageScore;
```

And add `if(scoreCount==0){}` condition to check if there is any previous input, so it doesn't divide zero by zero.

```
// get a series of test scores from the user
            while (testScore != 999) {
                // get the input from the user
                System.out.print("Enter score: ");
                testScore = sc.nextInt();

                // makes average score 0
                if (999 == testScore) {
                    //double averageScore;
                    averageScore = 0;
            }
                // accumulate score count and score total
                if (testScore <= 100) {
                    scoreCount = scoreCount + 1;
                    scoreTotal = scoreTotal + testScore;
                } else
                    System.out.println("Invalid entry: not counted"); 
            }

            // display the score count, score total, and average score
            if(scoreCount==0) {
               averageScore = 0;
            }else {
               averageScore = (double) scoreTotal / scoreCount;
            }
        } 

            String message = "\n"
                    + "Score count:   " + scoreCount + "\n"
                    + "Score total:   " + scoreTotal + "\n"
                    + "Average score: " + averageScore + "\n";
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
```

I compiled on my machine and the output for 999 is

```
Enter test scores that range from 0 to 100.
To end the program, enter 999.

Enter score: 50
Enter score: 50
Enter score: 50
Enter score: 42
Enter score: 999
Invalid entry: not counted

Score count:   4
Score total:   192
Average score: 48.0
```

And if I input 999 the first time, the output is:

```
Enter test scores that range from 0 to 100.
To end the program, enter 999.

Enter score: 999
Invalid entry: not counted

Score count:   0
Score total:   0
Average score: 0.0
```

And as Makoto pointed out: "NaN means "Not a Number" and is the result of undefined operations on floating point numbers like for example dividing zero by zero. (Note that while dividing a non-zero number by zero is also usually undefined in mathematics, it does not result in NaN but in positive or negative infinity)".

If you write 999 as first input, it gives you avarage score: NaN because it divides 0/0.

Comment: Division by zero with floats doesn't produce 0.

Comment: @Makoto Ok, I didn't see that at first but it's correct. Still works as bloocool wants from what I understood. I will update the answer when I analyze the problem a bit further